# Detect Mouse Movement and Direction in Godot

Tags: progress-bar, mouse, godot, godot3

I am making the `settings menu` for a game in **Godot 3.5** which has a `progress bar` node for the volume.
I want players to drag their mouse to adjust the volume, like so:
[image: image of volume bar]

The problem is that I don't know how to detect where and how much the mouse is moving to change the value of the progress bar accordingly.
I was wondering if there was a way to **detect and measure** mouse movement when it enters a node.

I tried to *use `get_global_mouse_position()`, stored it in a variable, used a timer for a delay and then again checked it, then subtracting both, I thought I would get the mouse movement* but it didn't work and the **progress bar remained the same.**
Although, even if it had worked, it would not have been smooth or changing realtime...

I hope you'd like to help,
THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `HSlider` for volume settings.

---

Since you want to use a `ProgressBar`...

A way to do this would be with [`_gui_input`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_control.html#class-control-method-gui-input) in an script attached to the `ProgressBar`:

```
func _gui_input(event:InputEvent) -> void:
    var mouse_event := event as InputEventMouse
    if mouse_event != null:
        if mouse_event.button_index == BUTTON_LEFT and mouse_event.pressed:
            prints(mouse_event.position)
```

Here the `position` you get would be in local space of the `ProgressBar`.

---

We could compute the value from the `x` (`position.x`) and the `width` (`rect_size.x`):

```
   x         value - min_value
------- = -----------------------
 width     max_value - min_value

=>

                            x
 (max_value - min_value) ------- = value - min_value
                          width


=>

value = min_value + (max_value - min_value) * x / width
```

**Note**: Be aware that the above computation does not take borders into account.

---

**Addendum**: I notice you explicitly ask "how much the mouse is moving". Well, if the `event` is an `InputEventMouseMotion`, it has a `relative` property that will tell you how much it moved since last event.